# How to install Fabric Mir BFT consensus?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Having seen a few talks on Mir which is apparently implemented within the Hyperledger Fabric chain, I am completely unable to find out how to install it - doesn't seem to be much on Hyperledger's site, Sawtooth seems to be currently the product of the day (which I already have, but only PBFT's available and we need something more performant).

Apologies if I'm being dumb about this. Just can't find them.

Answer (score 1):

Mir isn't implemented in Fabric just yet. It's future work.

There is, however, an [integration](https://github.com/SmartBFT-Go/fabric/) of [another BFT library](https://github.com/SmartBFT-Go/consensus/) in Fabric which is **not an official Hyperledger effort**.

The integration is based on Fabric v1.4 and is [publicly available on dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/u/smartbft).

The paper of the project can be found [here](https://smartbft-go.github.io/paper.pdf).